# Dante (SOCKS server) not working

Tags: proxy, socks, dante

I'm trying to set up a SOCKS proxy using dante for testing purposes. However, I can't even get it to work with a web browser, after looking at several tutorials on how to do that.

I've tried in both IE and Firefox, in both cases, using "Manual proxy configuration", leave everything blank except for SOCKS host, and then put in the IP of my proxy and the port number (1080). I just get "Server not found" / "Problems loading this page" and don't see anything in danted, even running in debug mode.

If I do a "telnet 10.0.0.40 1080" I do see the connection open in danted debug output, so I know that much is working.

Here's my config:

```
logoutput: stdout /var/log/danted/danted.log
internal: eth0 port = 1080
external: eth0
method: username none #rfc931

user.privileged: proxy
user.notprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody

connecttimeout: 30   # on a lan, this should be enough if method is "none".

client pass {
        from: 10.0.0.0/8 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}

client pass {
        from: 127.0.0.0/8 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}

client block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}

block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 127.0.0.0/8
        log: connect error
}

pass {
        from: 10.0.0.0/8 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        protocol: tcp udp
}

pass {
        from: 127.0.0.0/8 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        protocol: tcp udp
}

block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
```

I'm sure I'm probably missing something simple, but I'm lost. I haven't even thought about SOCKS since the late 90's.

Comment: Did you take a look at `/var/log/danted/danted.log`?

Answer (score 2):

this is bacuse of wrong config for your version of dante-server.

here is correct config for Dante v1.4.2

```
#logoutput: /var/log/socks.log

internal: eth0 port = 1080
external: eth0

method: username none
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

#accept connections from any source (bad way)    
client pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error connect disconnect
}

#accept from your white list source (good way way)
client pass {
from: 1.2.3.4/32 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error connect disconnect
}    

client block {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: connect error
}

pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error connect disconnect
}

block {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: connect error
}
```